# Display selected product variation on WooCommerce cart page

Tags: php, woocommerce

On my cart page I need to display the product variation selected by the customer:

```
productDisplayID = wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) );
$productDisplayName = get_field('product_display_name', $productDisplayID);
$productDisplayDescription = get_field('product_category_display_name',$productDisplayID);
printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a><br />', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $productDisplayName ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
echo '<span>'.$productDisplayDescription.'</span>';
if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
$available_variations   = $product->get_available_variations();
var_dump($available_variations);
}
```

I am using ACF to enhance my products with additional information; more natural sounding names and product descriptions. Under these two lines I would to display the variation selected. I've managed to 'dump' the product variation info and it outputs:

```
ARRAY (SIZE=2)
  0 => 
    ARRAY (SIZE=24)
      'ATTRIBUTES' => 
        ARRAY (SIZE=1)
          'ATTRIBUTE_PACKAGING' => STRING 'WITHOUT OUTER PACKAGING' (LENGTH=20)
.... more follows
```

What I would like to do is display the 'ATTRIBUTE_PACKAGING' underneath and I'm not sure how.

In actual fact what I really need to do is **only** display if the attribute is equal to 'WITHOUT OUTER PACKAGING'.

Would I use a foreach loop of some sort or can I access this directly?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly your question but I believe it might hold the answer for you...
Check this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/313187/woocommerce-list-variations-that-are-added-already-to-cart-in-single-product

Comment: Thanks @Shlomtzion for taking the time but this isn't quite the answer I am looking for. Useful code to know though.